# Converting JPEG 2000 to JPEG 

Tags: java, jpeg, jpeg2000

How do I convert JPEG 2000 to JPEG in Java? I have a biometric system that gets a fingerprint and and the user's ID number and the send it through the web service to verify the user. If a user has been verified I get back an Image in the form of a byte[]. Now The byte[] I get back is in JPEG 2000, I need to display it in my application, but i need to display a jpeg. I need to know How I can convert that to jpeg 2000.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to display the image as JPEG?

Answer (score 6):

http://code.google.com/p/jj2000/

> This project is a JPEG 2000 encoder/decoder written in pure Java. Its goal is to be a reference implementation of (at least) part 1 of the JPEG 2000 specification.